# How to create Stored Procedure only in SSRS dataset, not in database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm using SSRS 2012 to create a report, and its dataset gets data from a stored procedure. When this SP is created in advance in SSMS database, and then exec in SSRS dataset, it works fine.

But: I don't want this SP to be created in SSMS database, in order to keep database clean. **I want to write the syntax of SP directly in SSRS dataset=>Query type: Text==> and exec SP at the same time . Then maybe drop this SP directly in SSRS after use.**

Is that possible?

I have tried:

```
create proc LALALA as
begin
 SELECT top 100 *  from mytable 
end
GO

Exec LALALA
```

Above query runs well in SSMS, but failed with error ***'the size necessary to buffer the XML content exceeded the buffer quota'*** when writing in SSRS dataset=>query type: text.

I also tried:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('dbo.LALALA') IS NOT NULL)
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.LALALA
GO

create proc LALALA as
begin
SELECT top 100 *  from mytable
end
GO

Exec LALALA
```

Above works fine in SSMS, but failed in Report Designer ***'create/alter procedure' must be the first statement in a query batch. Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.'*** when writing in dataset query text.

Any one could give me some idea how to go around this problem? 
Greatly appreciated!

Comment: I wonder why you want to do this ? Seems like a lot of trouble for no reason (if you ask me)

Comment: This is against the nature of SP. Create separate `schema` (not 'dbo') and make your reporting procedures belonging it.

Comment: Hi Lode, I just want to keep my SQL database simple and clean, avoid creating too many sp for different reports....

Comment: Hi Ivan. I tried create another schema for the sp, but still show same error....

Comment: Your rationale for not putting this in the database is quite strange. If a stored procedure is needed it belongs in the database. Ivan already suggested using another schema which is the best option by far.

Comment: Hi Sean, I tried another schema, but it still doesn't work, showing same error...